# pattern for multiple dockerfiles and 1 package.json

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, package.json

Say I have this:

```
project/
   app1/Dockerfile
   app2/Dockerfile
   app3/Dockerfile
   package.json
```

each app might use a subset of the dependencies in package.json. Is there a good way to create a *lean* version of the package.json file for each sub-app?

I realized I wasn't clear about what the **problem** is - the problem is that each Dockerfile (each project) doesn't need all the dependencies in package.json, in fact they might each use only 20% or fewer of the dependencies. So to pare down the size of docker images, we may want a way to override package.json, something like this:

```
  project/
       app1/
          Dockerfile
          dependencies.json
       app2/
          Dockerfile
          dependencies.json
       app3/
          Dockerfile
          dependencies.json
       package.json
```

where `dependencies.json` declares a subset of the dependencies from package.json, eg:

```
{
  dependencies: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
}
```

or even more fun maybe:

```
{
   antiDependencies: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
}
```

the dependencies to *not* install or what not.

Comment: Why is it set up that way to begin with? Are you trying to approximate [_workspaces_](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/workspaces/)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe you realize that the question you linked doesn't have a valid answer, right? Using workspaces doesn't help you with Docker at all. Docker needs to have all of the files for the image locally, and if you only want the dependencies that are required in each project to be included, workspaces makes the problem more complex, not less.

Comment: Short answer: no, not really. You could write a script to filter out keys in dependencies/devDependencies from a parent package.json, and write those files into each subdir before building, but that gets unmanageable if you're using a lockfile (and you should, because it'll speed up the image builds). A much simpler solution would be to just have separate package.jsons for each subdir, though it sounds like you might have a codebase that makes that unreasonable?

Comment: hey Tim n Zac, thanks, I am surprised anyone understood OP given how it was written but I just improved it, so maybe @jonrsharpe  can understand it better now.

Comment: No worries, I understood the question just fine because I've had the same issue with client/server monorepo setups. We just used multiple package manifests.

Comment: @ZacAnger sounds cool, wouldn't it be cool to share one package.json?

Comment: It would be handy, and that's exactly what workspaces are meant to solve, but workspaces don't work well with Docker, due to Docker context starting in the directory of the Dockerfile. And the problem with manually copying over dependencies based on a filter list or whatever is that all the major package managers try to lift dependencies up and deduplicate (which would also cause problems with the lockfiles).

Comment: @ZacAnger you make some good points feel free to comment on the answer I made

Answer (score 0):

(Untested solution)

I think one potential solution is to do exactly as in OP:

```
// package.js

const pkgJson = require('../../package.json')

module.exports = Object.assign({}, pkgJson, {

    dependencies: {
       ...pkgJson.dependencies,
       // eliminate these:
       heavyDep: undefined,  
       anotherHeavyDep: undefined
   }

});
```

this is NOT a good solution b/c it's dynamic, but maybe get the ball rolling.

Comment: It is a potential solution, but because `npm` and `yarn` deduplicate and try to flatten the dependency tree where possible (and because this would mess with the resolution in lockfiles, which in turn could potentially lead to broken builds and _will_ lead to _slower_ builds), it's not ideal. If the parent/root `package.json` doesn't necessarily _need_ to have any deps, could it just contain metadata that the subdirs build on with a similar script?